# Axiom of Replacement in the cumulative hierarchy of sets

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I am reading the proof for the consistency of the axiom of Regularity relative to ZF - Regularity and what the book does is consider the cumulative hierarchy: 
$$P = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in Ord} V_\alpha$$
And prove that $P \models Extensionality, P \models Parinig, ...$ but the thing that confuses me is when we reach Replacement. So we have to prove:
$$ P \models \forall x \forall y \forall z [\varphi(x, y, p) \wedge \varphi(x, z, p) \rightarrow y = z] \rightarrow \forall X \exists Y \forall y [ y \in Y \leftrightarrow (\exists x \in X) \varphi(x, y, p)]$$
Given a $p \in P$ and assuming the first part holds, we get a function, $F = \{ (x, y) \in P: P \models \varphi(x, y, p)\}$.
Now we let $Y = F[X]$. (This part is confusing me): Since $Y  \subset P$, we have $Y \in P$.
Why? Why cant $Y$ be a proper subclass of $P$? How is this implication justified?
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: One approach that comes to mind is to use cardinals. But we don't have AC to well-order Y.

Comment: You could use Replacement to show that $Y $ must be a set in our domain of discourse, thus is not a proper class and therefore is an element of $P $ by the reasoning you gave.

Comment: But then shouldn't we prove that the notion of a proper subclass in our domain coincides with that of the model $P$?

Comment: Since we still don't know that $P$ is a model of ZF i don't think we can reason that the notion of a set in P is the same in an actual model of ZF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the fact that Replacement holds in the full universe you're working in.

Now look at a formula whose relativization to $P$ is functional, and apply Replacement outside of $P$. This gives you a set, so all you need to do is show that it lies inside $P$. But because you have a set, the ranks of its members only form a set of ordinals, so it must be a set in $P$.

Comment: Oh, haha. Thank you very much. And one side question: When we form the cumulative hierarchy $P$ inside a model of ZFC and try to prove that itself is a model of ZFC, are we actually proving that it's an elementary submodel? Or are we just assuming it to exist outside of that model and prove that it's a model?

Comment: @ShervinSorouri You cannot prove the cumulative hierarchy is a model of ZFC, as you cannot define a truth predicate over the cumulative hierarchy. What you have actually proven is each instances of axioms of ZFC relativized to the hierarchy holds.

Comment: @Shervin: When working inside a model of ZF, the cumulative hierarchy gives you *the entire model*. So yes, it is an elementary "sub"model. However, note that there is a lot of delicate issues about definability of truth, and what does it mean for a proper class to be "a model".

Comment: @Hanul: I'm not saying that it is a model but since we naturally assume that ZFC has one, then it should contain the cumulative hierarchy as a subset so by proving that ZFC holds in $P$ then haven't we actually proven that it's a model, on the premise that the initial model exists?

Comment: @Asaf : I don't understand why the cumulative hierarchy gives you the entire model (unless $V = L$ holds). Can't we have some imaginary sets in there? Like a large cardinal for example?

Comment: @Asaf: Can you explain a little bit, what you mean by the definability of truth?

Comment: @Shervin: $L$ has *nothing* to do with the cumulative hierarchy. It is its own constructible hierarchy, but that's a whole other thing.

Comment: @Asaf: Ok. Seems like i have much to study. Thanks.

Comment: @Shervin: Yes, but that is always true. :)